# Faxdocument cant be send by service from Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#

I have had a windows service app that sends tiff files using windows fax and faxdocument object working perfectly.
However, when I installed it on windows server 2012 it has stopped working for tiff files. It will send a fax with a text file however it will not send tiff files as the body of the fax.

I created a test windows app with the same code and it sends tiff files just fine from windows app.
Why on Windows Server it does not work, and how can i solve it?

Comment: So what version of Windows did it work on before? Have you tried enabling "Allow Desktop Interaction" for the service? The docs for FaxDocument.Body state "When you send a fax from a client computer, the body has to be associated with an application that is installed on that computer, and the application has to support the PrintTo verb; otherwise, the fax will fail", which may be a clue. Perhaps running procmon or something similar will let you see what's going on.

Comment: I don't know if it would make a bit of difference, but TIFF support comes in via the "Desktop Experience" feature.  Try running `Add-WindowsFeature Desktop-Experience` in powershell.